# Test for the existence of an integral

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

> Let $I_n=\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{-x}}{x+\frac{1}{n}} \mathrm dt$. Test for the existence of this integral.

**Proof:**

$(I)$ Consider $f_n:(\mathbb{R^+}, \mathbb{B(R^)})\to (\mathbb{R},\mathbb{B(R^+)}), x\to f_n=\dfrac{e^{-x}}{x+\frac{1}{n}} $. Then $f_n$ is continue hence measurable.
$\forall x\ge0, f_n(x)\ge0$ so $I_n$ exist in $\mathbb{R^+} \cup \{+\infty\}$.

(II) Let $n\in\mathbb{N*}$, $n$ is fixed. At $x=0$, there's no problem. At $x=\infty$, $f_n(x) \sim \dfrac{e^{-x}}{x}$. We have $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2\dfrac{e^{-x}}{x}=0$, hence $\int^{+\infty}f_n<+\infty$.

Thus $f_n$ is defined in $\mathbb{R}$.

**My question:** Why do we need the first part, I mean why do we need to prove that $f$ is measurable? Last year, when I learned about Riemann integal, I just have to prove the second part and that's enough. Now I'm learning Lebesgue integral and the teacher said that the first part is necessary. I still don't understand why. It's just the same question but why the proofs are different?

Comment: The Lebesgue integral is defined only for measurable functions.

Answer (score 1):

The integrand function is continuous, positive and by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

$$ I_n \leq \sqrt{\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-2x}\,dx \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\left(x+\tfrac{1}{n}\right)^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}. $$
This settles the existence of $I_n$ in a single line.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But my question is that  the first part, the fact that $f$ is measurable is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I try to explane of other form:

$I_n=\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{-x}}{x+\frac{1}{n}} \mathrm dx < \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{-x}}{x} \mathrm dx < \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \mathrm dx$

where $ \color{#C00000}{\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \mathrm dx =1}$

$I_n=\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{-x}}{x+\frac{1}{n}} \mathrm dx < 1 $

So I show that the integral exists, making use of squeeze theorem

Comment: Thank you for your help. But my question is that the first part, the fact that $f$ is measurable is necessary? Or we just need the second part?

Comment: Btw, I have a question. Can you please explain why do we have $\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{-x}}{x} \mathrm dx < \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \mathrm dx$?

Comment: the first part is just a way of being rigorous, since there is defining what type is your function, which is its domain and this way you begin to limit the nature of your function making it can be demonstrated in a simpler way in some cases.

Comment: you're right I've been wrong the demonstration I gave is only true, for an integral that goes from 1 to infinity